# SQL: How to create supplemental time-series records "out of thin air" from existing records

Tags: sql, etl

Suppose I have a table CUSTEVENTS listing customers active in certain months. I now want to consider a customer as being active even if it was in the prior two months.

Simple example, the data might start as:

| MONTH_ENDING | CUSTNUM |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-31 | 72378 |
| 2022-11-30 | 72378 |

It should be transformed into the following, given the expanded definition of active:

| MONTH_ENDING | CUSTNUM |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-31 | 72378 |
| 2022-11-30 | 72378 |
| **2022-12-31 | 72378** |
| **2023-01-31 | 72378*** |

I'm arrive at the simplest / most elegant way to get there.  I could certainly explode out the data using a time series reference table which would list all the pairs of MONTH_ENDING and "additional" MONTH_ENDING values that "count".  Or perhaps I could UNION three subqueries that take the MONTH_ENDING, add_months(MONTH_ENDING,1) add_months(MONTH_ENDING,2).  But, maybe there's something even more concise not involving multiple unioned queries or an instrumental time-mapping table.

I happen to be using Teradata but I'm not sure I care about platform-specificity; if there's a Teradata-only approach that works, I'll gladly take it.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is to first calculate the "Last" event time for a given customer, which is handled by something like

```
LAG(EVENT_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTNUM ORDER BY EVENT_DT)
```

The next concept is islands. You want to calculate that an island begins if the event happened after {your window} has elapsed from the prior one. Vice versa to calculate the island's end.

You can actually find some great online articles about this classic problem: Gaps and Islands problem.

If you understand CTE's, you can probably follow it through this example code I wrote. The first CTE is there to simply allow you to easily add a condition (instead of 1=1) for the events you care about.

```
WITH CTE_CONDITION AS (
  SELECT 
    EVENT_DT AS dtm, 
    CUSTNUM 
  FROM 
    My_First_Table 
  WHERE 
    1 = 1 
    AND EVENT_DT is not null
), 
CTE_LAGGED AS (
  SELECT 
    dtm, 
    CUSTNUM, 
    LAG(dtm) OVER (
      PARTITION BY CUSTNUM 
      ORDER BY 
        dtm
    ) AS previous_datetime, 
    LEAD(dtm) OVER (
      PARTITION BY CUSTNUM 
      ORDER BY 
        dtm
    ) AS next_datetime, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY CUSTNUM 
      ORDER BY 
        CTE_CONDITION.dtm
    ) AS island_location 
  FROM 
    CTE_CONDITION
), 
CTE_ISLAND_START AS (
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY CUSTNUM 
      ORDER BY 
        dtm
    ) AS island_number, 
    CUSTNUM, 
    dtm AS island_start_datetime, 
    island_location AS island_start_location 
  FROM 
    CTE_LAGGED 
  WHERE 
    (
      DATEDIFF(MONTH, previous_datetime, dtm) > 2 
      OR CTE_LAGGED.previous_datetime IS NULL
    )
), 
CTE_ISLAND_END AS (
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY CUSTNUM 
      ORDER BY 
        dtm
    ) AS island_number, 
    CUSTNUM, 
    dtm AS island_end_datetime, 
    island_location AS island_end_location 
  FROM 
    CTE_LAGGED 
  WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, dtm, next_datetime) > 2 
    OR CTE_LAGGED.next_datetime IS NULL
) 
SELECT 
  CTE_ISLAND_START.CUSTNUM, 
  CTE_ISLAND_START.island_start_datetime, 
  CTE_ISLAND_END.island_end_datetime, 
  DATEDIFF(
    MONTH, CTE_ISLAND_START.island_start_datetime, 
    CTE_ISLAND_END.island_end_datetime
  ) AS ISLAND_DURATION_MONTH, 
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
      CTE_LAGGED 
    WHERE 
      CTE_LAGGED.dtm BETWEEN CTE_ISLAND_START.island_start_datetime 
      AND CTE_ISLAND_END.island_end_datetime 
      AND CTE_LAGGED.CUSTNUM = CTE_ISLAND_START.CUSTNUM 
      AND CTE_LAGGED.CUSTNUM = CTE_ISLAND_START.CUSTNUM
  ) AS island_row_count 
FROM 
  CTE_ISLAND_START 
  INNER JOIN CTE_ISLAND_END ON CTE_ISLAND_END.island_number = CTE_ISLAND_START.island_number 
  AND CTE_ISLAND_START.CUSTNUM = CTE_ISLAND_END.CUSTNUM
```

I wrote this into a [Rasgo template](https://app.rasgoml.com/sql?transformName=%22summarize_islands%22&tableState=%7B%22tables%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22My_First_Table%22%2C%22columns%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22CUSTNUM%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22EVENT_DT%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22date%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%22baseTableName%22%3A%22My_First_Table%22%2C%22ddl%22%3A%22%22%7D&formState=%7B%22arguments%22%3A%7B%22group_cols%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column_list%22%2C%22cols%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22CUSTNUM%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22CUSTNUM%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A0%2C%22attributes%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%7D%2C%22conditions%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22math_list%22%2C%22values%22%3A%5B%221%3D1%22%5D%7D%2C%22date_col%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column%22%2C%22col%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22EVENT_DT%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22EVENT_DT%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A1%2C%22attributes%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D%2C%22buffer_date_part%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22date_part%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22MONTH%22%7D%2C%22buffer_size%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22int%22%2C%22value%22%3A2%7D%7D%2C%22transformName%22%3A%22summarize_islands%22%7D) using Snowflake syntax, but only minor adjustments should be needed to get this to work in Teradata.

Once you have this result, then this tells you the periods of activity that include the 2 month window. You can then use a calendar table at each month-begin and query or not whether the customer was "active" or not based on whether that date falls into these active ranges.